# How do I construct a loop to make conditional means in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, mean

I have a dataset in which observations are ranked based on priority. I want to find the conditional mean of one variable (whether or not they like the color red (1 or 0)) by groups of 100. That is, I want to find the mean of whether or not the top 100 observations by (by rank) like the color red. The mean will be something like 0.25 or something. Then, the mean of whether or not observations ranked 100-200 like the color red. Then, 200-300, and so on. There are around 18,000 observations total.

I tried to write the following loop:

```
lb <- seq(0, 18000, by = 100)
ub <- lb + 100

redgivenrank <- numeric(length(lb))

for (i in 1:181) {
  lb1 <- lb[i]
  ub2 <- ub[i]
  subset_datans <- subset(datans, datans$rank >= lb1 & datans$rank <= ub2)
  redgivenrank[i] <- mean(subset_datans$red, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

This ended up giving me vastly different values from when I did it manually, and then after a few rounds it just started giving NA values as the answer, so clearly something is wrong.

Manually, I did this to get the values:

```
mean(datans$red[datans$rank <= '100'])
mean(datans$red[datans$rank >= '100' & datans$rank <= '200'])
mean(datans$red[datans$rank >= '200' & datans$rank <= '300'])
mean(datans$red[datans$rank >= '300' & datans$rank <= '400'])
mean(datans$red[datans$rank >= '400' & datans$rank <= '500'])
```

This gave me actual values, but I notice one key difference is that, here, the numbers are 'quoted' versus in the loop they are not. What difference could this make? Which is correct for what I want to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If

```
datans <- data.frame(red = runif(18000))
datans$rank <- rank(datans$red)
```

then in base R you could do...

```
redgivenrank <- tapply(datans$red, floor((datans$rank - 1) / 100), mean)
```

On your question about the quotes, they will force both variables to be coerced to strings, so `>` will be an alphabetic comparison, not a numeric one. If they are all 3 digit numbers, the result happens to be the same, but generally it is better to keep numbers as numbers!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
data.frame(red = runif(18000)) |>
  mutate(rank = min_rank(red),
         group = ceiling(rank/100)*100) |>
  arrange(group) |>
  summarize(mean = mean(red), .by = group)
```

Result

```
    group        mean
1     100 0.002669958
2     200 0.007938085
3     300 0.013000659
4     400 0.018663290
5     500 0.024165192
6     600 0.029287301
7     700 0.034077178
8     800 0.039054385
9     900 0.044447559
10   1000 0.049864560
...
```